# What database does Commerce Runtime make use of?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a storemanager dashboard which makes use of Microsoft Dynamics AX database. To avoid writing a lot of code, I plan on using CRT (commerce runtime) which would give me some form of abstraction and also saves my time writing a lot of code by using other integration methods like AIF and .net business connector.

But, my doubt is, the description of CRT says that it makes use of CRT channel database.

Will it have required amount of data that ax database would have and is it the right way to go forward, when you have to make use of Dynamics AX database (central db) that has all the data?

Comment: This seems to be a question only a requirements analysis can answer. Only you or your customer can decide if the crt database already has (or can easily be customized to include) the information that you need for the storemanager dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/jj916620.aspx) of the Commerce Runtime Architecture.

If the dashboard can use the services of the CRT, then use that.

The CRT database is not the AX database and contain a subset of the AX data, and is asynchronously updated using a one- or two-way sync depending on the data.

You will have to decide whether this is okay for your application.

Comment: thanks for the help @Jan B.Kjeldsen , is there an api that directly connects to microsoft dynamics ax database and provides some form of abstraction ? it would be really helpful!!

Comment: There is the .Net Business Connector: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa659581.aspx

Comment: yes using that at the moment, but doesn't provide any abstraction :/

Comment: Plenty, make the abstractions in AX or use the built-in.